# Firestore - how to exclude fields of data class objects in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore here explains, how I can use simple classes to directly use them with firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

How can I mark a field as excluded?

```
data class Parent(var name: String? = null) {
    // don't save this field directly
    var questions: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
}
```

Comment: You have two distinct questions here.  One is about excluding Kotlin fields from serialization with Firestore.  The other is about serializing a reference type field.  They are not really related to each other.  In order to make this question more searchable for people who have one *or* the other question, I've edited the question to address only the exclusion of Kotlin fields from serialization.  The question about reference types I answered as a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225103/with-firestore-how-do-i-serialize-a-reference-type-field-with-a-java-class/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Kotlin creates implicit getters and setters for fields, you need to annotate the setter with [@Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) to tell Firestore not to use them.  Kotlin's syntax for this is as follows:

```
data class Parent(var name: String? = null) {
    // questions will not be serialized in either direction.
    var questions: ArrayList<Child> = ArrayList()
        @Exclude get
}
```

Comment: Aren't you annotating the getter in your example? Why you say the setter needs to be annotated?

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is super late, but I just stumbled upon this and thought I could provide an alternative syntax, hoping someone will find it helpful.

```
data class Parent(var name: String? = null) {
    @get:Exclude
    var questions: ArrayList<Child> = ArrayList()
}
```

One benefit to this is that, in my opinion, it reads a little clearer, but the main benefit is that it would allow excluding properties defined in the data class constructor as well:

```
data class Parent(
    var name: String? = null,
    @get:Exclude
    var questions: ArrayList<Child> = ArrayList()
)
```