# With Firestore, how do I serialize a reference type field in a document with a java class?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a Firestore document with a field of type "reference", how do I read and write that field when using automatic POJO Java object serialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POJO fields of type [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) and [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) will automatically be populated with [document and collection reference type fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#references) from a Firestore document.

Comment: I edited the question and added a simple example. Could you also answer my question I added at the end?

Comment: Well, you completely changed the question from how I originally posed it.  It would have been more appropriate to ask a new question with the specific details you wanted.  I'm going to roll back to the original so the question and answer make sense together.