# No properties to serialize found on class UserProfile in debug build

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, proguard

I am trying to get a `UserProfile` document from Firebase Firestore for `UserProfile.kt` class but I am getting the following error only in debug build. Everything works as expected in release build for the class definition given below.

Stack Trace []:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
No properties to serialize found on class com.pune.dance.fitness.api.user.models.UserProfile

com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:187)
com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:165)
com.pune.dance.fitness.api.user.UserApiManager$getUserProfile$1$1.onSuccess (UserApiManager.kt:44)
```

This is how my UserProfile.kt looks like:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
@RealmClass
open class UserProfile : RealmModel {

    @get:Exclude
    @PropertyName("user_id")
    @PrimaryKey
    var userId: String = ""

    @get:Exclude
    @PropertyName("name")
    var displayName: String = ""

    @get:Exclude
    @PropertyName("mobile_number")
    var mobileNo: String = ""

    @get:Exclude
    @PropertyName("fitness_session_id")
    var fitness_session_id: String = ""

    @get:Exclude
    @PropertyName("session_timing_id")
    var session_timing_id: String = ""

    @get:Exclude
    @PropertyName("diet_plan_id")
    var dietPlanId: String = ""

}
```

When I use annotations as written below, for each field, then firestore creates 2 entries in database for each field. Here, `user_id` & `userId`, these 2 entries and made in firestore database only in release build but no such duplicate entries are made in debug build.

```
@set:PropertyName("user_id")
@get:PropertyName("user_id")
var userId: String = ""
```

And below, I am giving my release 7 debug build definitions along with proguard rule:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Proguard rules:

```
#To preserve the info Crashlytics needs for readable crash reports
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

#Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android
#For faster builds with ProGuard, exclude Crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

# Keep custom model classes
-keepclassmembers class com.pune.dance.fitness.api.*.models.** { *; }
```

I am not able to understand this weird behavior. I have tried almost every possible combination of annotations and I need to understand why the Above given definition `UserProfile.kt` crashes for debug build only.

Comment: Have you tried to use that annotation in the constructor?

Comment: @AlexMamo No, what annotation we need at the constructor?

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50915292/5246885).

Comment: @AlexMamo  I don't need a parameterized constructor as shown in the link